# How to change eps float value to geographic meter distance

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, parameters, pandas, spatial-cluster

I have a problem in making distance meter parameters for the DBSCAN tool. The problem is that I don't know the eps unit to use and how to change it to meters to be a parameter. Here's the Python script I made:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
in_file = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
eps = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
min_sample = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))

#Convert the feature class to a pandas DataFrame
array = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_file, ["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"])
df = pd.DataFrame(array)

#Extract the X and Y coordinates from the DataFrame
coords = df[["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"]].values

#Get the spatial reference of the input feature class
describe = arcpy.Describe(in_file)

#create spatial object
SR = describe.spatialReference

#Create a spatial reference object
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(SR.FactoryCode)

eps_m = SR.metersPerUnit * eps

#Function DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_sample).fit(coords)

#visualization of db_scan
plt.scatter(coords[:,0],coords[:,1],c= db.labels_)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.title("Grafik Data compound DBscan")
plt.show
print("Jumlah Kluster:{}".format(len(set(db.labels_[np.where(db.labels_!=-1)]))))
print(db.labels_)

labels = db.labels_

#Export feature class
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
out = arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(array, output, ["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"])

#Add field cluster into feature class output
cluster = arcpy.AddField_management(output,"CLUSTER","Short")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output,["CLUSTER"]) as cusor:
    for i, row in enumerate(cusor):
        row[0] =labels[i]
        cusor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eps or Epsilon in DBSCAN is the "The maximum distance between two samples for one to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other." (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html).

The units are the units of your data. The default value is .5. If you are working in meters, then this would be a maximum distance of .5 meters. I think that input data in sci-kit learn are typically normalized first (e.g. between 0 and 1, or standardized). That's probably why the eps default is .5.

I would start by finding the minimum distance between your points and using that as your first eps value. Not exactly the same, but this is an example that uses nearest neighbors to identify a value for eps: https://medium.com/@tarammullin/dbscan-parameter-estimation-ff8330e3a3bd

Also, you can use different cluster metrics like homogeneity score: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html to find the optimal eps value for your dataset. This will require several iterations to find the best combination of eps and min_pts.